# three.js - How to make an object look like on ground when put in a sphere panoramic scene(I have jsFiddle)

Tags: three.js

```
jsFiddle here:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/liyuanqiu/77gpwaxx/3/

Note: You must open this link in http not https

I put a green cube in a sphere scene, like this:[image]

Look in far:
[image]

I want to make the green cube look like it is on the ground, but don't know how. Can someone give me some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've increased the size of your sphere and positioned the cube, is this the `effect` you were after? http://jsfiddle.net/4sv5xu0a/

Comment: You inspired me, thank you. Put my object on the edge of sphere of ground can achieve my goal.

Comment: Glad it helped!